# expl3: partially expand an argument

Tags: expl3, expansion

I wish to assign a `\crefname` with dynamical strings. With `\exp_args_generate:n { xVV }`, I ended up with something like:

```
\exp_args:NxVV \crefname {\__my_countername: }
                         {\csname my@cref@\__my_countername:\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname @name\endcsname}
                         {\csname my@cref@\__my_countername:\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname @name@plural\endcsname}
```

Here `\__my_countername:`  is the counter's name, such as `theorem`. `\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname` is a conversion from string like `english` to `EN`.

However, this expands the arguments too deeply that the strings are no longer dynamic with respect to the context. To be clear, I wish the arguments to be expanded to:

```
\crefname {theorem }
          {\csname my@cref@theorem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname @name\endcsname}
          {\csname my@cref@theorem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname @name@plural\endcsname}
```

That is, to make `\__my_countername:`  expanded while keeping `\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname` untouched, since it should receive `\languagename` from the context. Would that be possible?

I tried to use `\noexpand`, but probably misused, which leads to an error with no warning text.

*(Please forgive my terrible mixture of expl3 and LaTeX2e code, I'm not familiar with expl3 and it would be much easier for me to use a little LaTeX2e code for some tasks)*

Comment: Like that you can't.  When you expand `\csname` once, it expands and collects everything up to the (matching) `\endcsname`, so all macros (including `\languagename`) are expanded.  There is not much you can do here, because both the inside and outside `\csname`s vary with `\languagename`, so you should probably leave that unexpanded.

Comment: P.S.: The `V` expansion works on a single token/variable.  Feeding it multiple tokens (`\csname...\endcsname`) is wrong and works by pure chance.  The correct form here would be with `v` (but then it expands the `\csname`, which you don't want): `\exp_args:Nxvv \crefname {\__my_countername: } { my@cref@\__my_countername:\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname @name } { my@cref@\__my_countername:\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname @name@plural }`.  The `v` expansion is short for `c` _then_ `V`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Is there any way to expand only `\__my_countername:`? If it is not expanded, an error would occur, though I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the whole code, but if you only want to `x`-expand `\__my_countername:`, then `\exp_args:Nx \crefname { \__my_countername: } { ...`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, actually this was my original code. But I want also the `\__my_countername:` in the last two arguments get expanded (and leave everything else untouched). Would that be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Became too long for a comment:

If you want to expand `\__my_countername:` and keep everything else unexpanded, then you can use `x` expansion in all arguments, and keep other tokens from being expanded with `\exp_not:N`:

```latex
\exp_args:Nxxx \crefname { \__my_countername: }
  { \exp_not:N \use:c { my@cref@ \__my_countername: \exp_not:N \use:c { \exp_not:N \languagename ABBR } @name } }
  { \exp_not:N \use:c { my@cref@ \__my_countername: \exp_not:N \use:c { \exp_not:N \languagename ABBR } @name@plural } }
```

(I replaced `\csname ... \endcsname` with the more `expl3`-y `\use:c { ... }`).

The above would expand only the three `\__my_countername:` (which sounds like it's misnamed).  But that's doing the same work three times, so you can instead define an auxiliary macro and expand `\__my_countername:` just once, making the code a bit faster, and a *lot* easier to understand:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__my_crefname_aux:n #1
  {
    % In this macro, #1 is \__my_countername: expanded
    \crefname {#1}
      { \use:c { my@cref@#1 \use:c { \languagename ABBR } @name } }
      { \use:c { my@cref@#1 \use:c { \languagename ABBR } @name@plural } }
  }
% then use it as:
\exp_args:Nx \__my_crefname_aux:n { \__my_countername: }
```